# The "return" statement

Tags: javascript, return

I had a question about the return statement that is by itself in the control flow.

```
var rockPaperScissors = function(n) {  
    var rounds = n;
    var results = [];

    var weapons = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

    var recurse = function(roundsLeft, played) {
        if( roundsLeft === 0) {
            results.push(played);
            return;
        }

        for(var i = 0; i<weapons.length; i++) {
            var current = weapons[i];
            recurse( roundsLeft-1, played.concat(current) );
        }
    };

    recurse(rounds; []);
    return results;
}
```

I was wondering why the return statement is not written as:

```
return results.push(played);
```

Is there any benefits? If so, why and when should you write it that way?

Comment: you have a small syntax error: it should be `recurse(rounds, []);`. It should be a comma instead of semicolon

Answer (score 1):

That's because `recurse` is only being used for its *side-effects* (namely, for what it does to `results`), not its value. The return is still necessary so that the recursion bottoms out, but other than that, there is no reason to return anything from `recurse`.

Answer (score 1):

`return;` is the same as `return undefined;`, so basically return nothing.
It is the same effect as if the function would finish without a return statement.

`return results.push(played);` returns the result of `results.push(played);`, which may not be undefined.

If you ignore the return value of your function `recurse`, there is no difference, which is the case in your function `rockPaperScissors`.